# Android Mindorks library, how to call fragment method from Data class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am a beginner android developer and I am stuck with this problem. For anyone who has used the Mindorks library maybe you are able advice on how to do this.

Code used below:

```
@Layout(R.layout.tinder_card_view)
public class TinderCard {

@View(R.id.profileImageView)
private ImageView profileImageView;

@View(R.id.nameAgeTxt)
private TextView nameAgeTxt;

@View(R.id.locationNameTxt)
private TextView locationNameTxt;

@View(R.id.profileInfo)
private ImageButton info;

@Click(R.id.profileInfo)
void openProfile()
{
  //Call the fragment method 
}


private Profile mProfile;
private Context mContext;
private SwipePlaceHolderView mSwipeView;

public TinderCard(Context context, Profile profile, SwipePlaceHolderView swipeView) {
    mContext = context;
    mProfile = profile;
    mSwipeView = swipeView;
}

@Resolve
private void onResolved(){
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Bitmap bitmap = mProfile.getImage();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    Glide.with(mContext).load(byteArray).asBitmap().into(profileImageView);
    //profileImageView.setImageBitmap(mProfile.getImage());
    nameAgeTxt.setText(mProfile.getName() + ", " + mProfile.getAge());
    locationNameTxt.setText(mProfile.getLocation());

}
```

I have a limited understanding of the Mindorks library. My goal is for the tinder_card_view layout to have a button that would open a DialogFragment which would display the user's profile.

How will I be able to do this? TinderCard is a simple data class that is neither a Fragment nor Activity but the layout it is using is not within the scope of the ParentFragment so calling the onClickListener in the ParentFragment from this class looks to be impossible.

I am calling mSwipeView.addView(new TinderCard(mContext, profile, mSwipeView)); in my Parent Fragment to create a TinderCard and place it on my SwipePlaceHolderView (Mindorks class) that would hold the Tinder cards.

Source tutorial is here:
https://blog.mindorks.com/android-tinder-swipe-view-example-3eca9b0d4794

Note: @Click is an annotation which sets the onClickListener to the element defined in the enclosing parentheses. (I think)

Comment: I eventually called the Dialog directly from the onClick method in the TinderCard class.

Comment: Can anyone close this?

Comment: You can add your own answer and accept it.